# General place to see required rep for privileges

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

Is there a standard for where each SE site should link to its required reputation for privileges? I was searching for that for a particular SE, and only found it by doing a web search for `privileges stack exchange` and finding Stack Overflow's, then guessing that the URL structure would be consistent.

That's a pretty weird user experience. Is there a better way to find it?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the *Privileges* page from your *Edit Profile & Settings* under the *OTHER* section.

In other way, by URL `https://<sitename>/users/edit/current` then under *OTHER* section.

> [image]

another way, from the top bar when click the *Recent achievements* icon, there is a dialog popup will appear. In the popup the link for the *privileges* page is available.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is standardized.

```
https://{site}/help/privileges
```

For a simpler URL, you can use `https://{site}/privileges`, which redirects to the URL above.

Alternately, visit the "Help Center" for any site, and there's the link in the middle column at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find it by clicking the "?" icon on the right side of the top bar, clicking "Help Center", and then clicking "View a full list of privileges you can earn" in the bottom middle.